# Best way to pass large binary data to C from Lua

Tags: c, lua

I have an app where I get a large binary data from network (500KB) via LuaSockets. (Didn't implement this part yet). Based on what I know this data will be stored in some sort of String or a table or an array.

I need to complex processing on this data and I have an existing, proven ANSI-C Lib for this, I need to pass the data to the C. The approaches I have looked at usually pass the data in the call stack which would not work for me due to the data size.

The existing ANSI-C lib expects a pointer to the data and the size. I can probably wrap this API with a new API where it excepts the data byte by byte and finally once the whole size is established call the real API however this means huge number of calls to some C function from Lua and not preferred since I want performance.

What is the best way to pass this large data to C? (I have considered writing to a file and passing file name but this is not preferred, I really want a direct memory pass)

Comment: "*Based on what I know this data will be stored in some sort of String or a table or an array.*" Which is it? Those are 3 completely different things.

Comment: @NicolBolas that itself is another question Nicol. Lua is not very strict typed, I basically don't know. But based on what I read, it seems connected:receive([size]) returns the datagram in String format.

Comment: Note that while LuaSocket does pass binary data in Lua strings (which is a fully supported and recommended practice, incidentally) it does not guarantee that any particular call produce an entire datagram. Further, if you are moving 500KB, it will certainly never collect a buffer that large to be returned in a single call. You will want to build up your data body incrementally from the strings returned by `receive()`. One good way to do that would be to collect them in a table and pass the whole table to the C side.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that LuaSocket provides data as a string, then it's really simple.

Your C application will be passed the string directly from Lua. So it's on the Lua stack. Use `lua_tolstring` to get the string and it's size. This will return a pointer to Lua-owned memory (so you need to ensure that it remains on the Lua stack or in the registry or somewhere while you're using it, to prevent Lua from garbage collecting it). Then pass that string+size to your API of choice.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you dont have to care for the Lua stack size. Most if not every element on the Lua stack are actually heap allocated. If you are usinf luasocket, then the binary data you received is already available as Lua string (the return value of socket:receive i guess), so you are not extra-allocating anything! The Lua stack actually is more likely to pass around sort of references, so copying does not take place or is very cheap.
To interface your C lib you may:
a) wirte a C binding
b) use alien 
c) luajit
in 99% of all cases i'd prefer a). There are several ways to do this, but it seems to be a rather slim C API, so i'd do it without any extra binding libs (like luabind).

You may have a look on lua-cjson source http://www.kyne.com.au/~mark/software/lua-cjson-manual.html. That's a good example of a C binding.

Answer (score 1):

I would skip luasocket and just using a C/C++ socket library if I were in your case.

Since the processing is going to be done in C/C++ anyway, using luasocket simplifies (a little) the socket handling at the expense of complicating (significantly) the interfacing between the received data and the C/C++ binary data treatment lib.

Using a C/C++ socket lib will make the socket handling a bit harder (but not much) while the data transmission to the treatment lib will be trivial.

Comment: Ok. I respect your POV. The reason I stick with LUA is cross platform compatibility of LUA. (Android vs. iOS) I am now looking at MOAI and Gideros as potentials. I really don't want to port the whole UI and experience hence the current thinking. Are there any cross platform C/C++ socket lib are you aware of?

Comment: I don't understand. How do you plan to use a C/C++ data parsing lib if you are using MOAI or Gideros?

Comment: Both MOAI and Gideros are good in integrating with C, simpler on Gideros. The engine I do the complex work is written in C, so I basically do all the complex calculation and data parsing in C and pass back the results to LUA. LUA will run the box2D and other UI elements and interface. I reallly don't want to touch UI code across platforms and this is the primary motivation for me to use this cross development tools.

Comment: In that case, I recommend you just use the C part of LuaSocket - It's a dual lib, with a C part and a Lua part. Your C/C++ could surely speak with its C. And since it's a relatively popular library someone will probably have some experience with it on Gideros/MOAI, so you might find help if you get stuck. (Disclaimer: I have not tried it that way, but I think it could work)